# VSCode Python extension clobbers Javascript tag/symbol search

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

With `vscode-python` installed, I can't find Javascript symbols in my Python + Javascript project.

When I hit Command-T for "Find Symbol in Project", I only see Python symbols, but my project has loads of Javascript & JSX files too. If I'm editing one of those files and hit Command-T, I see all the Python symbols plus the Javascript symbols *in that file*, but no wider.

I figure this is something to do with the way that `vscode-python` registers itself as a symbols provider and runs `ctags` with `--language=Python`. While there are various settings for `vscode-python`'s use of `ctags`, adding Javascript support to the invocation doesn't *seem* to be one of them.

Does anyone know how I can get symbol search for both languages at once?

Am on a Mac, running VSCode 1.25.1, `vscode-python` 2018.6.0, `exuberant-ctags` 5.8.1 (from Homebrew).

Comment: Feel free to file a bug at https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python